# Can't set QModelIndex in Qt5

Tags: qt, model-view-controller

Here is a timer routine that updates the contents of `QTableView` (`partyView`) after executing the SQL query. If worked well, but when I converted my program from Qt4 to Qt5, it started giving me segmentation fault in the last line:

```
void MainWindow::on_timer()
{
    QModelIndex idx=ui->partyView->currentIndex();
    partyModel.setQuery(partyModel.q_main+partyModel.q_where);
    ui->partyView->setCurrentIndex(idx);
}
```

What was changed in `QModelIndex`, and how to avoid this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the code...

```
partyModel.setQuery(partyModel.q_main+partyModel.q_where);
```

Does that update the underlying model to which `ui->partyView` is attached?  If so then it may well invalidate the `QModelIndex` returned by `ui->partyView->currentIndex()`.

Try using [`QPersistentModelIndex`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpersistentmodelindex.html) instead.

```
void MainWindow::on_timer ()
{
  QPersistentModelIndex idx = ui->partyView->currentIndex();
  partyModel.setQuery(partyModel.q_main + partyModel.q_where);
  if (idx.isValid()) {
    ui->partyView->setCurrentIndex(idx);
  } else {

    /*
     * idx is no longer a valid model index -- do something appropriate.
     */
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't say I'm aware of any *specific* changes from `Qt4` to `Qt5`, but a `QModelIndex` is, strictly speaking, a temporary object that can be invalidated by any changes to the underlying model.  I think you just got lucky (or unlucky depending on your point of view) with `Qt4`.

Comment: @MichaelO. Undefined behavior is bound to bite you sooner or later.